# Why css3 transition height not easing in and out

Tags: html, css

I want to code so that when I hover over an image the a div below has it height changed, it changes but with no ease please help. I want to know why the ease is not working, what am I doing wrong and what should I fix and how!

```
.pic1{
    width:400px;    
}

.f1{
    height:0px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease ;
}
.pic1:hover .f1{
    height:auto;
}

</style>

<div class="pic1"><center><h3 style="color:#00afef;">FlexMount S15</h3><br>
<a href="http://www.mobotix.com/other/Products/Cameras/FlexMount-S15" target="_blank">    <img src="images/mo1.jpg" alt="" data-scroll-reveal="over 0.9s enter left ease-in-out 400px"/></a><br></center>
<div class="f1"><br>
    <ul>
    <li>Weatherproof dual camera system (IP65) for flexible mounting solution</li>
    <li>Two separately connected, discreet miniature sensor modules</li>
    <li>Image sensor and microphone integrated directly into the sensor module</li>
    <li>Double Hemispheric equipment replaces up to eight cameras</li>
    <li>Integrated DVR functionality: Slot for MicroSD card (up to 64 GB)</li>
    <li>Functional expansion via MiniUSB and MxBus connector</li>
    <li>S15M &amp; S15 Hemispheric: Available July 2013</li>
    <li>S14 sensor modules cannot be used with S15 models (and vice versa)</li>
    </ul>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example using `jsFiddle`?

Comment: I dont know what jsFiddle is

Comment: `height` won't ease in and out if you use `auto` as the value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PkSerero/Jh8gm/

Comment: Ok let me try it with a value thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/DuChs/

The problem is that you can't apply transitions to `height`, if one of the heights is `auto`.  By using `max-height` instead (and setting it to be larger than your content you want to display), you get the desired result.

```
.f1{
    max-height:0px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease ;
}
.pic1:hover .f1{
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: also, its better to not use the `center` html element, it's putting layout in the markup, which is not ideal.  maybe you can get around that with a bit more css instead?

Answer (score 0):

Height: auto does not work with transitions. You have three options:

Use the transition with max-height value.
Put a static height instead of height: auto. For example height: 100px;

```
.pic1:hover .f1{
  height:100px;
}
```

Use CSS3 ScaleY property like this

```
   #child0 {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);

    -webkit-transform-origin: top; 
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #dedede;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}

#parent0:hover #child0 {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Regards.